# Uncaught ReferenceError: openModal is not defined when using Modal bootstrap using Asp.net vb,

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'am sorry if this question look like a repeated question, but hear me first.
1st, i'm using asp.net vb and material dashboard design and i'm not using mvc concept.

I want to show modal success/fail message whenever insert, update or deleted. the modal will be triggered in code behind (vb).

This is my modal inside of site master.

```html
                             <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">testing</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
    </form>
    
</body>
       <script type="text/javascript">


           function openModal() {
               $('#myModal').modal('show');
           }


</script>
```

and this here is my script code,

```js
function openModal() {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

and this is my code behind in vb

```
 Protected Sub btnTesting_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTesting.Click
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "openModal();", True)
End Sub
```

and the error is Uncaught ReferenceError: openModal is not defined.

So, where is my mistake?
did I forgot something?
Or do you have any other way to triggered modal using code behind?

For your information, I'm a newbie in asp.net. Before i'm more on PHP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the `openModal()` function defined? Is it in an inline `javascript` tag on the `ASPX` page or is it in a seperate Javascript file?

Comment: @Loyalar in the same page at site master.

Comment: So it's defined in an inline script tag on the masterpage? Can you edit your post to show the script tag and where it is on your masterpage?

Comment: @Loyalar I already update. do you mean like this?

Comment: @kaizokuhimura can you show me how your page structure looks like . i need to see how you are referencing the jquery files and where you are calling the modal method in the site master

Comment: @Webruster 1st, i'll let you know that I don't have any problem to call modal using jquery if the triggered is in aspx page. but whenever i'm trying to call it at code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript, i got the error.

so, i put all my modal inside of master page, at the bottom of it. same with the jquery file, i put it at the bottom of master page. outside of </body>

Comment: @kaizokuhimura try with the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` see it worked or not

Comment: @Webruster still have same problem.. may i know when to use 'this.Page, this.Page.GetType()' and '(Page, Page.GetType()' ?

Comment: @kaizokuhimura try to set the last attribute with False

Comment: @Webruster nothing happen. Oh ya, if i changed the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "openModal();", True)` into `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "alert('test');", True)`, it's worked. but it's just a simple alert not a modal..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153860/discussion-between-webruster-and-kaizoku-himura).